# Jquery mobile navigation stack when logout and go back to login

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

My phonegap app, I want to bring back login when user logs out. But If I use,

```
$.changePage('#login');
```

after logout. It makes navigation stack unmanageable specially navigating with Android back Button . Can I reset my Navigation stack after logout.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$.mobile.navigate('#login');
```